# How do I reconfigure domain in SAP BusinessObjects 3.1?

Tags: weblogic, business-objects

I have got full copy of productive server and new server name is `NEW_SERVER`. Also, I've created new CMS on this server and it's running well. But I've deployed war files to my development Weblogic server, created with JDeveloper, and they give me error:

> Server OLD_SERVER:6400 not found or server may be down (FWM 01003)
> null

So how can I reconfigure Weblogic or this war files to look at `NEW_SERVER`? It seems like I should reinstall Business Objects and they will reconfigure automatically to look at my current server, but I hope to avoid this.

Comment: So it's only your web application that's giving you issues? I assume you're talking about a custom web app, not the WAR files delivered by BOBJ? Do you have the source code available?

Comment: @Kristof, no, I'm speaking about war files delivered by BOBJ. I have got two servers in one network. OLD is productive and NEW is for development, made by image of OLD one. Now I hope there is a chance to change this WAR files without reinstalling Business Objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to reinstall BusinessObjects. If all that has changed is the server name of your BOBJ server, and your new server is running fine (meaning the SIA and CMS are running, along with the other servers), you only need to change the `web.xml` configuration files of the BOBJ web applications.

Look for the `web.xml` files in the `InfoViewApp` and `CmcApp` folders (you'll have to look inside the WAR files or otherwise use `wdeploy` to create new WAR files). Search for the old server name (should be somewhere at the top) and replace the value by the new server name.

I'm not familiar with WebLogic (most BusinesObjects installations use Tomcat), but you'll have to restart the two web apps, the WebLogic server or redeploy the WAR files for the changes to take effect. After this, you should be good to go.

If you still see the old server name appearing in the logon forms for InfoView or CMC, try clearing the cookies in your browser.

More information:

- the [web application deployment guide](http://service.sap.com/~sapidb/011000358700000718972008E)
- SAP KB [1206342](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1206342) - How to change the name to the system without effecting the Infoview and CMC in XI R3

You'll need an active SAP support account to view both links.